# starter master page for sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page

I am building a new master page for our SharePoint online site. Do we have a minimal or starter master page specifically for SharePoint online?

Comment: Refer [Link 1](https://startermasterpages.codeplex.com), [Link 2](https://www.lynda.com/SharePoint-tutorials/Using-starter-master-pages/87093/93352-4.html)

Answer (score 4):

There's no "starter" master page template that I can think of, other than simply copying an olso or seattle and going on from there.

That said, I highly recommend rethinking this approach if you can. Built-in master pages are routinely overwritten by updates, so unless you babysit them, any custom master page you author will become out of date and will eventually break. Also, modern pages do not inherit from the custom master page setting.

Here's a really good write up on this: [Adding Custom Branding to SharePoint Online and Office 365](https://www.degdigital.com/insights/dos-and-donts-for-creating-custom-sharepoint-online-designs/)

And one regarding custom master pages and modern team sites: [Customizing "modern" team sites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites), specifically under the "What's not supported" section:

- Custom master pages - More extensive branding will be supported later using alternative options
- Changing "modern" site to use classic seattle.master or oslo.master

Community: Please chime in on this. I'd like to know your thoughts and be corrected myself if I'm missing something.

Comment: CSS can do wonderful things as well!